# What is MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT?

Tags: android

According to ref. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html I am wondering, what is `MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT` ?

Is it one of the rest value like `THREE_GPP` or other ?

How can I figure it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEFAULT will be one of the other formats listed. It is simply the default output format for that device.

Note that this format could be device specific. See this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for more details on supported Android video formats.

If you wanted to verify this, you could write a simple app that creates a video using DEFAULT and saves it to SD, then check the format.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for reply. But is it possible to check what value is set right now as a default ? Something like `getDefaultOutputFormat()` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to programmatically get the default. The only thing I can think of is to actually record a small file and the check the format. The formats that come with Android are guaranteed to be available, so you could always just specify a particular format.

Comment: getDefaultOutputFormat() has no sense, because it would always return MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT.
It's like asking what is the value of 2. You don't have to call getValueOf2(), right?
Just look what value it has and compare it with the rest of the possible values.